# How to find MAC address of another device in Java or Android

Tags: java, android, networking

How can I find MAC address of another device (Cellphones, Printers, Computers) on LAN using Java or Android? I had read all the answer related to this there but most of them are finding MAC address of their own Device which is possible.

What I need is I put IP address of another device on my LAN and it will return the MAC address. The code which I am currently trying is mentioned below.

```
public static String findMACForIP(String IP) throws SocketException, UnknownHostException {
    NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(InetAddress.getByName(IP));

    if (network != null) {
        byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int x = 0; x < mac.length; x++) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[x], (x < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));
        }
        Log.d(Config.TAG, "MAC:" + sb.toString());

        return sb.toString();
    }

    return null;
}
```

The above code clear means that it is trying to find the interface to which the given IP is assigned, so in case of someone other computer/device it will be not able to find that interface as that exists on that device, not our so it will return null as a result I am receiving null.

But when I input my own device IP(android device IP) it is returning its MAC address since the above can find an interface with that IP.

What I want is someone another computer MAC. it is possible because there are many apps on google play store which actually get the MAC address of all the device on LAN.

Comment: It should be in the ARP table.

Comment: Yes on desktop ARP table is right thing, but on Android phone its not possible because there no arp command

Comment: ARP happens. You just need to look in the ARP table to see the resolution.

Comment: yes thats great, i just get into adb shell and try to run the arp command that is not working, please let me know if there is other way to test

Comment: Not with the `arp` command. The table is in the device, and you need to look in the table.

Comment: yes you are right i can get the table using cat /proc/net/arp

Comment: the issue is it doesn't list all the devices

Comment: i saw an application when i use scan it show all the IP address in arp table from 192.168.0.1-192.168.0.255

Comment: The ARP table gets populated when you try to access a device by IPv4 address. Your host will use ARP to resolve the IPv4 address to the MAC address, and it will populate the ARP table. Entries in the table will eventually time out.

Comment: Great i tried to access all he devices on the LAN an now it got populate great (Y) thanks for your help

Comment: IPv6 doesn't use ARP, it uses ND, and it maintains a few tables for that.

Comment: most of the networks uses IPv4 so i need that for now

Comment: In 2018, it is foolish to not use both IPv4 and IPv6. You should use both for anything you do, otherwise you may find yourself scrambling with something unfamiliar.

Comment: Good suggestion